# How to use catch

Tags: haskell

The documentation on catch seems scanty, and examples few. I am trying to handle the case where a file check fails due to the file being non-existent. If you do not refer to the argument of the lambda in the body of the lambda with a type qualification the code will not compile (that is remove the let which does nothing). Why not?

```
-- checks if file is readable
checkFileAccess :: FilePath -> IO Bool
checkFileAccess f = do
  catch (fileAccess f True False False)
            (\e -> do
               let _ = e :: IOException
               return False)
```

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but see also [`catchIOError`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/System-IO-Error.html#v:catchIOError).

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question, I first tried

```
(\(e :: IOException) ...
```

and found that to do that you need to turn on `-XScopedTypeVariables`, and this is somewhat deprecated. Then I realised that the lambda expression is just that, an expression, and therefore you can apply a type specification to it:

```
-- checks if file is readable
checkFileAccess :: FilePath -> IO Bool
checkFileAccess f = do
  catch (fileAccess f True False False)
        ((\_ -> return False) :: IOException -> IO Bool)
```

This is a solution. And very elegant. Haskell always astonishes me with its deep coherence.

Having said that, I feel the code to do this check is somehow not idiomatic Haskell. Is there a better way to do this check and deal with IO exceptions?